# 'is used to thinking' vs. 'is used to think'

Tags: grammaticality, difference, infinitives, gerunds

> To an economist or a journalist who is used to ***thinking*** of a decade as long enough for entire theories to rise and fall, an age is the longest period imaginable; durable ideas can be age-old and this age is synonymous with 'this world' or 'everything'.

Can anyone explain why ***thinking***, and not ***think*** is used in that passage?

Would it be ungrammatical replacing ***thinking*** with ***think***?

Or, otherwise, that replacing would be grammatical but it would produce a change in meaning. If so, can anyone explain what this change in meaning is?

Comment: Again, *be used to [noun phrase]* is an idiom.  Here, the NP contains a gerund, the form of a verb that functions like a noun.  The *to* in this idiom is not an infinitive marker, so it can't be followed by an infinitive verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good trick to avoid such confusion is to remember that there are two different entries **used to** in a dictionary. The typical usages are:

- [**used [infinitive]**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to) is for habits in the past. Here, ***used to*** is a verb, e.g., *I used to play badminton.*
- [**used to [verb-ing]**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/used-to_11) (also **used to [noun]**) is for familiarity. Here ***used to*** is an adjective, and you always need *verb to be* in front of it, e.g., *I've lived in Central London for six years now, so I'm used to driving in London now. I'm used to the noise too*.

Compare these two sentences:

> **I am used to playing** badminton.
>   **I used to play** badminton.

The first (**I am used to playing**) means: I have played badminton often enough, so you can expect me to know what badminton is and to play it well enough. The second (**I used to play**) means: I played badminton regularly for a certain amount of time in the past. (I don't play it anymore.)

In your question, it would be ungrammatical if you replaced **thinking** with **think**. Do not write <del>*"He is used to think ..."*</del>. Always write ***"He is used to thinking ..."*** to mean that he is familiar with that kind of thinking. However, if you want to mean that he changed his opinion, use *"He used to think ..."*. For example, *"He used to think smoking is good."*

Answer (score 1):

for more information, I would like to post some differences of some similar forms of used to.

1. [used to + general verb] means habitual actions in the past but now he or she doesn't do this.
2. [be used to N/-ing] is also used as [be accustomed to N/-ing]
3. [be used to + general verb] is passive form and if you use for instead of to, you can put the reason or purpose at the end of this expression.