# I used to study at Cambridge School

Tags: semi-modals

I ***used to*** study at Cambridge School.

I ***am used to*** studying at Cambridge School.

If the verb is continuous tense, it need to be added "verb to be" before used to?

Comment: Do you mean to phrase it like .. "I am used to be studying at Cambridge school"

Comment: I answered it once here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14097/3281. It's better to think of *I'm used to V-ing* as *I'm familiar with V-ing*; and think of this *V-ing* as a gerund (or something that works as a noun), not a continuous tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used to study at Cambridge School.

This sentence discusses an action that happened entirely in the past.

> I was studying at Cambridge School.

That would be past continuous.

---

*To be used to something* is a special phrase that means being habituated.  For example, "I am used to eating spicy foods, so this dish tastes bland."

Therefore,

> I am used to studying at Cambridge School.

actually means, "I have a habit of studying at Cambridge School," which doesn't really make sense.  It could make sense if you added some details: "I am used to studying at the Cambridge School library, which offers free Wi-Fi access to the academic journals I need.  When I do my studying anywhere else, I find it very inconvenient."

---

Incidentally, if you are talking about the [University of Cambridge](http://www.cam.ac.uk/), you would usually just say "Cambridge":

> I used to study at Cambridge.  Now I teach at Oxford.

Comment: There is such a thing as the Cambridge School (sometimes Cambridge School of Languages). It is for language learners. See for example http://www.cambridgesol.edu.ec/index_n.html . Actually there are many institutions with "Cambridge" in the name that are not the University. I have known people from these institutions say "I went to Cambridge" or "I studied in Cambridge". Not actually lying, but deceptive. There _is_ a difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no continuous construction in either of these sentences. Rather, the *used to* collocation has two distinct meanings, taking two distinct sorts of complement.

> A. *SUBJECT* used to *VERB*<sup>INFINITIVE</sup>.

Here *used to* is employed as a pseudo-modal verb expressing a past habit or state. Like true modals it takes the infinitive form of a lexical verb as its complement.

> I used to study ...

Note that this expression is never used in any form or construction except the simple past.

> B1. *SUBJECT BE* used to *NP*.
>   B2. *SUBJECT BE* used to *VERB*<sup>GERUND</sup>.

Here *used to* is employed as a transitive adjective meaning, approximately "accustomed to" or "inured to". It takes a Noun Phrase or Gerund Phrase as its complement.

> He was used to hardships.
>   I am used to studying for three hours every night.

In B2-type constructions, *VERB* may be *BE*, either as the main verb or as an auxiliary—but it has to be in the gerund form.

> He was used to being hungry.
>   He was used to being mocked.

It is theoretically possible to use *BE* here in a progressive construction, but it's very artificial, in part because English speakers dislike adjacent *-ing* forms. I find it difficult to think of a situation in which this would arise naturally.

> <sup>?</sup> I am used to being studying by six o'clock every night.

Comment: Hi Stoney. Since the sentence is not progressive is it correct to say "*Ergative is occasionally used to categorizing verbs.*"? I think in this case *"to"* is a preposition.

Comment: @Abbasi No. You may express purpose with a 'marked' infinitival *to VERB* or with a preposition phrase *for VERBing*, but not with *to VERBing*.

Comment: Let me ask this question: Is "to" a preposition in the sentence?

Comment: @Abbasi Historically it derives from the preposition, but traditional (19th-early 20th-century) grammar regarded it as component of the infinitive, and modern grammarians tend to call it an 'infinitive marker' or a 'subordinator'.

Comment: I know that it is most of the times part of full infinitive but there is some *to* on the list of prepositions which seems to be that.

Comment: Do you say *to* is not a preposition but part of full infinitive "to categorize" there?

Comment: @abbasi Orthograhic or phonetic 'words' may belong to mutiple word classes, even 'function' words like prepositions. No, I do not regard the *to* as a part of the infinitive but as a 'marker' which signals that the form is employed as an infinitive. Some constructions require it, others prohibit it, and yet others permit it without requiring it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52625/discussion-between-abbasi-and-stoneyb).