# Is "bother" an ergative verb?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

I have [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_ergative_verbs) list for comparing verbs for their being ergative or not. As you see, *bother* is not on that list. But I have sentences in which that verb seems to be ergative.
For example:

> She may bother to sweep the room just now.
> Joseph bothered by the cancellation.
> Sally bothered.

Is *bother* an ergative verb? If not, what are the meanings of those immediately above sentences please?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I wonder whether it belongs on ELL as written. I am a native AmE speaker (for many decades) and reasonably well-educated, but was not familiar with the term *ergative*. Would English Language Learners really know this word?

Comment: @shoover: I'm a Kurdish person and since I'd like to learn each part of English grammar, I focused on this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bother* indeed has both transitive and intransitive senses, and they all have the general sense "trouble"; but they are used in slightly different ways.

- Transitive *bother* means to "cause trouble" for a person, who is cast as the direct object. When the subject is an animate agent, it typically means to annoy the DO by intruding on the DO's activity; when the subject is inanimate, it typically means to worry the DO.

  > My little brother won't stop bothering me when I'm trying to work.
  >   This proposal bothers me.
- Intransitive *bother* means to "take the trouble" **to** do something. It is typically used only in negative contexts.

  > Don't bother to clear the table; I'll put my stuff away in a minute.
  >   If she won't bother to tell us what the problem is I don't see how we can help.

None of your three sentences is quite idiomatic. The first has no negative to trigger use of *bother*; the second lacks a passive auxiliary (***was*** or ***is*** bothered), and the third lacks a negative and the obligatory infinitival complement.

*Ergative* is occasionally used to categorize verbs like *bother*, and I used it back in ELL's early days; but it has a distinct technical meaning in other contexts, and snailplane suggested a better term: [*labile*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/labile_verb).

Comment: Thank you. So does :"*Don't bother to clear the table*" mean "*Don't take the trouble to clear the table*"? Is the ""take the trouble"" meaning the same as above in "*if she won't bother to tell us*" too?

Comment: Do you agree "*is occasionally used to categorize*" should be "*is occasionally used to categorizing*"?

Comment: @Abbasi To your first, Yes. To your second, No: *used to VERB*, *used for VERBing*.

Comment: The last question on the answer your supplied. Is "*Did you bother?*" correct? And can we mean the word *bother* when it's in negative and intransitive form as "*don't take the trouble*" in sentences commonly? (I will make a new thread shortly on the *"subject + be/get used to + verb*" and "*subject + used to + verb*". Thanks you so much.

Comment: @abassi *Did you bother?* is fine: the question 'accommodates' a negative understanding. And *Don't bother* is fine, too. Note that both presuppose an infinitival (*to VERB*) recoverable from the context. ... We have many questions about the contrast between adjectival *used*+prepositional *to* and verbal *used*+infinitival--for instance, [http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/23682/32]. Look for them before posting anything.

Comment: Sure! Thank you so much. I wish I'd be your student. +1 for your comments too.

Comment: One comment on that thread on be/being.

Comment: @StoneyB -- I posted a draft tag wiki for [labile-verbs] in the [tag wiki drafting zone](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2849).

Answer (score 1):

Bother is not an ergative verb by my understanding, specifically in the cases of the sentences provided. In those sentences, the meaning of bother/bothered changes.

1. She may *choose/decide* to sweep the room right now.
2. Joseph [was] *concerned* by the cancellation.
3. Sally *fussed*.

In these instances the verb would not make sense if the subject had changed.

I based this using the definition and text provided by [Ergative verb - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb)